# Quicken Direct Connect Script/Logic/Add-On Support

Tags: quicken

Does Quicken support user scripts, logic, or add-ons? I want to do some programmatic intrabank transfers (which requires the Direct Connect method) but if Quicken supports these kinds of functions they certainly make it tough to find.

Comment: I can't find any clear statement either way, but I don't think it does.  I would imagine the possibility of accidentally using malicious scripts makes any sort of widely-used "script library" unlikely.  Someone could trick you into downloading and running a script that would give them all your money.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, talking to your bank about setting up "recurring payments" might be the right solution; Quicken would then download those transactions like any other transaction. (I have my credit union automatically transferring money from savings to checking, and from checking to my mortgage-payments account at another bank. I'd presume other banks can do the same things.) Theoretically recurring transactions can be set up in Quicken too, if you've given it the ability to send orders to the bank as well as read data from it. But it sounds like you want something fancier.

Comment: My bank can do recurring transfers but, like most banks they are very limited. They can only do fixed value transfers on (at the most frequent) a weekly basis. I want to do variable transfer amounts on a non-fixed schedule - like filling a Per Diem checking account from whatever it's current balance is up to $20, everyday except weekends. Hence the need for a tool that can directly conduct intrabank transfers AND accept scripting. I think I've found a solution but I'll need to do some more digging before I bring it back here...